# Getting exception in report generate from PMD in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, pmd

I am getting error in report generate from PMD.

net.sourceforge.pmd.PMDException: Error while parsing /Users/**/**.kt
..

```
apply plugin: 'pmd'

pmd {
    toolVersion = "6.27.0"
}
task pmd(type: Pmd) {
    description 'Run PMD'
    group 'verification'
    ruleSetFiles = files("./code_quality_tools/rules-pmd.xml")
    source fileTree('src/main/java/')
    include '**/*.java'
    include '**/*.kt'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination(file("$project.buildDir/outputs/pmd/pmd.html"))
    }
    ignoreFailures = false
}
```

Comment: hey @Sunny, did you manage to solve this issue? facing same here.

Comment: @ThiagoSouto No. Replaced PMD with some other tool